# Difference between `pkgin` and `pkg_*`, and which to use?

Tags: freebsd, netbsd

Coming from Linux land, I assumed that `pkgin` is some sort of higher-level frontend for `pkg_add` et al, something like what `apt` is to `dpkg` or `yum`/`dnf` to `rpm`. But `pkg_add` appears to handle installation from network, dependencies, as well as automatic updates (the things that on Linux would be the responsibility of the front-ends rather than the underlying package tool), so now the roles of `pkgin` and (what I gather are the more traditional) `pkg_` tools seem a bit unclear to me. The only difference that I'm presently aware of is that `pkgin` does not handle installation from sources.

- What is the job of each, and how are they different?
- When / why should I prefer one over the other?
- Are there any issues with mixing the two, or using one to update software acquired using the other?
- Are these differences likely to hold across the different BSDs? I'm getting my feet wet with NetBSD, for example, but the `pkg_` tools and `pkgin` appear to be part of FreeBSD as well.

Comment: I don't know the other BSDs, but on FreeBSD you use [`pkg`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg) to install packages.

Comment: And FreeBSD doesn't have anything called `pkgin`. You should read [the Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html)

Answer (score 3):

They are two different tools that have evolved independently from each other. The pkg* tools are the native NetBSD tools for package management, while pkgin wants to be a tool similar to apt-get or yum. Neither handle installation from sources. That's the job of p[kgsrc](https://cdn.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/current/pkgsrc/doc/pkgsrc.html), but both can install binaries built from pkgsrc.

"man 1 pkgin" and "man 1 pkg_add" is all you need.